# StackFrame of an Iterator Block in C#

Tags: c#, debugging, iterator, stack-frame

I am using an iterator block as coroutine, that is, I have an enumerator IEnumerator e; e was initialized, and in the middle of an iterator block, yield return 1; was used to hold the execution of the coroutine temporarily.

For the purpose of debugging, it is desirable to get where e was yielded, i.e., the stack frame of  e. It may be viewed in the debugger, or it may be logged for future inspection.

But all I have is IEnumerator interface, which has only three methods and one property. And I can't figure out how to relate them to, say, System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.

Is it possible, or should it be possible?

EDIT: After immediately receiving two comments clearing up my question I *really* want to ask, the *correct* question is:

You have a yielded IEnumerator e. Is there a way to get, for mostly debugging purpose, as much info as possible on what would be the *resumed* state? The MethodBase together with file name and line number would be perfect.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean - but while it's not executing, there *isn't* a stack trace... the closest you've got is the state field within the iterator, which tells it where to jump to next time you call MoveNext.

Comment: An iterator is a state machine, not a co-routine.  It does not have a dedicated stack.  You can *emulate* a co-routine with an iterator but that's where the buck stops, you get no extra help from the debugger.